# Chat + feed multicolumn

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, feed

I was wondering if it wouldn't be better to have an OPTION to put the tag feed in its own column on the same page.

The page is readable even with two columns. Maybe the feed could be pushed under the chat users in the room.

Only 1% of users still use resolutions below 1024*800. So room shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: You're assuming that all users with screen widths greater than 1024 browse maximized. They do not. Stop assuming you have a lot of horizontal space. Things are crowded enough on my screen as they are. Adding more columns would make things even worse.

Comment: I said it could an option. I think your minus vote is a bit harsh. If your subscribed to a popular tag, it can be hard to follow the chat itself

Comment: How do you know about that 1% ? Some people block google-analytics, if you refer to that (I don't vote in any direction since I don't disagree with this as an *option*)

Comment: Ok, got me there... But still, if you have the option for it, it wouldnt matter anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's now the option to send new feed items into a dedicated ticker area, I consider this `status-completed`, even if the problem was solved without adding another column (which, as [insert Welbog's name of the day here] pointed out correctly, would be a screen space real estate issue).

Answer (score 0):

You can mute the feed user and use a plugin for your browser which shows the RSS feed separately. But maybe one of our greasemonkey-magicians will come up with an easier solution